# Is there a way to select a Property within a List?

Tags: c#, list, lambda, reflection, expression

```
class A{
 public List<B> List {get; set;}
}
class B{
 public string Property {get; set;}
}
```

I would like to write a PropertyExpression simular to this:
`Func<A, object> x = y => y.List.Property`

Is this even possible? And how can this be achieved?

Comment: from which element of the list you wana get this property?

Comment: Maybe it works with: `.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == variable)`. Or `.Single(x=>x.Id...)`.

Comment: No, i need the "path" to the property, .FirstOrDefault() and .Single() do not work.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not that much clear but hope you are asking for something like this.

I'll initiallize the objects as follows.

your properties :

```
class A{
 public List<B> List {get; set;}
}
class B{
 public string Property {get; set;}
}

            List<B> bb = new List<B>()
            {
                new B { Property = "AAA" },
                new B { Property = "BBB" }
            };

            List<A> aa = new List<A>() {
                new A {List = bb }
            };
```

Assume you want to check whether a value is there assigned to property in class B.

```
    var isExists= aa.Any(xx => xx.List[0].Property == "AAA");
```

Likewise you can use any LINQ expression.

Comment: Sadly this is not the Soultion. Sorry for the bad question. I need a "path" or a "pointer" to a Property in the List. Something like ```Func<A, object> x = y => y.List.Property``` without even instantiating a object of the Class.